# Questions are not aligned in user's list of questions

Tags: bug, user-interface, activity

In the list of questions asked by a user (on the user's "Activity" page), the questions are not aligned. The alignment of questions that have answers differs from the alignment of questions that have no answers.

Example 1:

[image: Example 1]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

I am using Firefox 88 on Ubuntu.